# issues with python 3.x packages in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, smtplib

I tried to install smptlib package to send mails using python 3.x in pycharm. But when I searched the package in the available packages , I
couldn't find it. So , what do I do now to send mails using python?

Answer (score 1):

smtplibaio is an async version of smtplib for python3:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smtplibaio/2.1.1

You can find usage examples here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Example:

```
>>> from smtplib import SMTP
>>> with SMTP("domain.org") as smtp:
...     smtp.noop()
...
(250, b'Ok')
```